# Snowflake - First Proc - What is wrong with Syntax

Tags: procedure, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE "PUBLIC".PHONE_DATA_ROLLUP()
  RETURNS VARCHAR
  LANGUAGE javascript
  AS
  $$
    var rs = snowflake.execute( { sqlText: 
      'INSERT INTO PROC_LOG ("PROC_NAME","EXEC_TIME") SELECT ''value 1'' AS "PROC_NAME", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as "EXEC_TIME";'
       });
   return 'Done.';
  $$;


CALL PHONE_DATA_ROLLUP();
```

**Error:**

> SQL Error [100131] [P0000]: JavaScript compilation error: Uncaught
>   SyntaxError: Unexpected string in PHONE_DATA_ROLLUP at '      'INSERT
>   INTO PROC_LOG ("PROC_NAME","EXEC_TIME") SELECT ''VALUE 1'' AS
>   "PROC_NAME", CURRENT_DATE as "EXEC_TIME";'' position 62

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would highly recommend using backquotes for SQL strings in a JavaScript procedure, as well as variable binding, eg

```
var rs = snowflake.execute( {
  sqlText:  `INSERT INTO PROC_LOG ("PROC_NAME","EXEC_TIME")
             SELECT :1 AS "PROC_NAME", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as "EXEC_TIME"`,
  binds:    ["value 1"]
});
```

The main advantages are:

1. You can use *both* 'single' and "double" quotes without any protection contamination
2. Strings can be multiline

Both features are highly useful with SQL code.

Answer (score 2):

in Javascript like this you can escape single quotes with a backslash (`\'`) instead of double single quotes (`''`)

```
...
'INSERT INTO PROC_LOG ("PROC_NAME","EXEC_TIME") SELECT \'value 1\' AS "PROC_NAME", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as "EXEC_TIME";'
...
```